# Getting 'Context is not constructible. Add a default constructor or provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, ninject, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am getting this error when I try to use code first migrations.

My context has a constructor with the connection name.

```
public class VeraContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public VeraContext(string NameOrConnectionStringName = "VeraDB")
        : base(NameOrConnectionStringName)
    {
    }

    public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<IntCat> IntCats { get; set; }
}
```

This connection name is injected with ninject when the project runs, I have also specified it as a default as in the above code but this did not help.

```
kernel.Bind<IDbContext>()
    .To<VeraContext>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("NameOrConnectionStringName", "VeraDB");
```

When I try to add migrations with "Enable-Migrations" is throws up the error:

> The target context 'VeraData.EF.Infrastructure.VeraContext' is not
>   constructible. Add a default constructor or provide an implementation
>   of IDbContextFactory.

If I remove the constructor from `VeraContext` it will work but creates another database with `VeraData.EF.Infrastructure.VeraContext` as its name.

I presume that `ninject` only passes the connection string when the project runs and not when I use code first migrations. Anyway I can inject/provide a default for the connection name when using code first migrations ?

Comment: All the ninject stuff happens when someone somewhere is doing a `Kernel.Get`. You need to either add a default ctor or wait for someone to tell you how to hook the migrations stuff to construct objects via Ninject (which I guess is what you're doing!).

Comment: You'd have to implement the `IDbContextFactory` for the results to be consistent (or your migration from code won't work etc.). Essentially you need a default ctor (that's the error) - but just implementing it would lead to problems.

Comment: The `IDbContextFactory` is no good for injection, it simply won't work- by design.  Can't see the point of it yet...

Answer (score 20):

Essentially you need a default ctor (that's the error) - but just implementing it would lead to problems.

You'd have to implement the `IDbContextFactory` for the results to be consistent (or your migration from code won't work etc.).

> Migrations actually call your default constructor to make a
>   connection. So you're other `ctor` won't matter much.

Here is the basic factory...

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext Create()
    {
        return new MyDBContext("YourConnectionName");
    }
}
```

You should combine that with injection, to inject and construct your DbContext as you wish.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean further, you can't inject, as the `Create()` doesn't take parameters and there must be a default constructor, which is always the one called- hence, nowhere to inject.  At least, no constructor-injection.

Comment: @nicodemus13 it was a longtime ago, but as I remember - it's to ensure consistent DbContext construction. oftentimes EF invokes default ctor by automatism, whether you want it or not, so you need to have one, and custom ctor doesn't get called. Factory is primarily for EF calls, you can use the injection on DbContext normally. But b) as far as I recall most IoC containers (I don't use ninject much) have way of defining e.g. container.Create<MyDbContext> and then some anonymous method to engage the factory (if the factory is more complex so you need to go through it, otherwise just as I said)

Comment: @NSGaga - Any reason why we cannot inject the DbContext or the connection string into the MyContextFactory through constructor and then return the DbContext instead of new'ing up a new DbContext in the create method?

Comment: @dotnetter you could do all sorts of things - but, DbContext is usually short-lived, one off object - and (in 99% cases) shouldn't be saved, reused or even more used as a singleton (it could lead to issues). EF on the other side keeps the core info inside a static and it's reused over different instances, so that the whole create, tear-down is efficient. In short, there's no need to do such optimizations, if I'm getting right what you're after here.

Comment: @NSGaga thanks. That makes sense. But I tried injecting (IoC) connection string name rather than hardcoding it and it didnt work.

Comment: @dotnetter ...into factory (like the above)? injecting how exactly, you gotta be careful with injection. Also this is pre-version-6 though much of the logic should be similar.

Comment: Using a factory, how could we inject our connection string into the factory with the `Enable-Migrations` command so that it can call our non-default constructor with our connection string of choice? It seems there's no way not to hard code the connection string when using migrations...and thus as @nicodemus13 mentioned, the factory is rather pointless.

Comment: @crush, it was a while ago, I guess my point was about the second ctor (not being a plausible solution). I'm not sure how to inject (non-hardcoded) connection in case of Enable-Migrations. I'm guessing there must be some injection support on the EF side by now but I didn't check that recently (that's probably the way to go).

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to spend time looking into the IDbContextFactory option, and to get things working create a default constructor and hard-code the name of the connection string when calling the base DbContext:

```
public class CustomContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomContext() :base("name=Entities") {} 
}
```

SRC: http://www.appetere.com/Blogs/SteveM/April-2012/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Migrations

Comment: Isn't the whole point of using Ninject (or any IoC) so that the connection string name can be configured independently of the actual DbContext? So why would one hardcode the connection string name like this? `Enable-Migrations` provides a command line option to provide a connection string name to the command. The question I have is how can we then inject that connection string name into our DbContext classes when constructing them. Seems like that is what the OP was after too.

Answer (score 2):

To complement @nccsbim071 answer, I have to add one more thing... this option doesn't like constructor with default parameters... for instance:

```
public MyContext(bool paramABC = false) : base("name=Entities") {...}
```

instead you have to create a non-parameter (default) constructor and the parameter-constructor like old fashion way.

```
public MyContext() :base("name=Entities") {...} 
public MyContext(bool paramABC) : this() {...}
```

NOTE:

- `Entities` in this case means the connection string name... By convention, the name of the context is the same as the connection string name and since `MyContext` is not the same as `Entities`, it's necessary specify it manually.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I wanted to use the default connection factory, instead of explicitly providing one. Somewhere inside EF6 it'll try to lookup the factory, but it fails with this exception message. Stepping through the EF6 code, I found that Glimpse.Ado was wrapping the connection factory, which made [the lookup](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/02104044fae2aca5d3a1f50f55f4af940a3c64a8/src/EntityFramework/Utilities/DbProviderFactoryExtensions.cs#L28) fail to find a match.